# Sorting Adapter List Based on text

Tags: android, sorting

Hi i Adapter as follows

```
public class ApplicationInfo implements Comparable<ApplicationInfo> {
    public String name;
    public String packageName;
    public String status;
    public Drawable icon;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ApplicationInfo another) {

        MainActivity cls = new MainActivity();
        cls.sort(ApplicationContext.getAppContext());

        if (cls.sort(ApplicationContext.getAppContext()) == 1){

            return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name); // ascending

        }else if (cls.sort(ApplicationContext.getAppContext()) == 2){

            return another.name.compareToIgnoreCase(name); // descending

        } else if (cls.sort(ApplicationContext.getAppContext()) == 3){

            if(status.equals(another.status)){
                return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
            }else {
                return status.equals("Not Installed") ? 1 : -1;  // installed up along with ascending names
            }

        } else if (cls.sort(ApplicationContext.getAppContext()) == 4){

            if(status.equals(another.status)){
                return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
            }else {
                return status.equals("Installed") ? 1 : -1;  // not installed up along with ascending names
            }

        } else
            return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name); // ascending

    }

}
```

now what i want to do is that i want to also add sorting based on package name including name and install status

for example

sorting 1 and 2 makes name ascending and descending

and sorting 3 and 4 makes first check Name and then check status

now what i want is sorting 5 and 6 which check name and then check install status (same as 3 and 4 which is working fine) and also check package name

so if the app is

ABC
a.b.c
Installed

BCD
a.a.a
Installed

it should sort the list like below

app with name and package name and installed at top

Comment: why dont you use Comparator interface

Comment: could you give me example ? i am totally confused how to do it cus i already added two checks first check status and then name and align now getting confused to implement all 3 in one

Answer (score 0):

i made it worked yes

```
        if(status.equals(another.status) && packageName.equals(another.packageName)){
            return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
        }else {
            if(status.equals(another.status) && !packageName.equals(another.packageName)){
                return packageName.compareToIgnoreCase(another.packageName) ? 1 : -1;
            }else{
                return status.equals("Installed") ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
```

hell yeah i am genius ;)
totally confusing but worked

first it check app name then it check installed then it check packagename

u can move installed code up and package down to make it vice versa